# AssertTrue in try/catch

Tags: java, webdriver, assert

Please what exactly am i doing wrong.

I have checked and checked but all to no avail.
I have also checked previous code but I am not getting an error so my code works fine but just slight error somewhere.

The code is running fine and `assertTrue` is behaving as expected but when I put it in the `try`/`catch`,  I only get the log in the catch block, even when text was found.

I believe that if the `assertTrue` found the text, it should go to the next line of code in the `try` block and pass the test rather than the `catch` block. Don't get me wrong, I am not getting any error just that it's printing out the wrong message.

Code below including print out message in console.

```
public boolean verifyTextPresent(String value) throws Exception {

    Thread.sleep(5000);     
    try{
        boolean txtFound = driver.getPageSource().contains(value);
        log.log(value + " : text Found, .......continue");
        return txtFound;        
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        log.log(value + " :NOT Found, check element again ot Contact developer.");
        return false;
    }   
}

public static void verifySignOutBtn() throws Exception
{
    log.header("VERIFY IF SIGN_OUT EXIST AND CLICKABLE.........");

    callMethod.myAccountPageNative(CONSTANTElements.SIGN_IN_LINK);
    Thread.sleep(2000);     

    log.header("LOCATE SIGN_OUT BTN, AND CLICK ......");
    callMethod.elementPresent_Click(By.cssSelector(CONSTANTElements.SIGN_OUT_BTN));
    Thread.sleep(4000);         

    log.header("VERIFY SIGN_OUT NAVIGATES TO HOME PAGE WHEN CLICKED......");        
    try{        
        Assert.assertTrue(callMethod.verifyTextPresent("SIGN IN"), "SIGN IN");          
        log.log("User Successfully Signed Out.......");
        log.log("Test Passed!...");
        //callMethod.close();
    }
    catch(Throwable e)
    {
        log.log("User NOT Successfully Signed Out.... Contact developer.");
        log.log("Test Failed!...");
        //callMethod.close();
    }
    callMethod.close();
}
```

}

```
Msg in console:
SIGN IN : text Found, .......continue
User NOT Successfully Signed Out.... Contact developer.
Test Failed!...
```

The confusing part is that why is it printing out the `catch` block instead of the next line in the `try` block?

Comment: why do you think `try{
        boolean txtFound = driver.getPageSource().contains(value);
        log.log(value + " : text Found, .......continue");}` wouldn't print `Found`?

Comment: @jhamon .........  Thanks for your response......Don't get wrong. the verifyTextPresent() behaves as expected. i only added that method so that you can see how the method was written. The issue is why is the catch block printed and not the try block in the verifySignOutBtn()? pls read my question again.... tanx

Comment: well, there is 2 try/catch blocks and you don't sat which one is faulty. With those informations, I would say that `veryTextPresent` always return false. Edit: LordAnomander is right, swap the `assertTrue` parameters.

Comment: @jhamon Yes, but obviously an exception is thrown otherwise the test would fail, but the log within `catch` should not be printed. Thus, the method either doesn't work (and throws and exception) or `assertTrue` is used the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only possible explanation is that `verifyTextPresent(String value)` returns `false` (you never actually check the value of `boolean txtFound`) and `assertTrue` fails (throwing an `AssertionError` which is not handled well in your catch block). To find out, replace this

```
log.log(value + " : text Found, .......continue");
```

for example with this line

```
log.log(value + " : text Found, ......." + txtFound);
```

or just print the stacktrace in catch block.

Comment: @Wurgspab OMG! never believed i never saw that. you're damn right. the verifyTextPresent() was returning false because i never actually verified if it was found or not. And True, i added the try/catch to get rid of the AssertionError i was getting and catch a Throwable. Now Have amended the verifyTextPresent() and works perfect. Below is the code.

Comment: `public boolean verifyTextPresent(String value) throws Exception {
  
  Thread.sleep(5000); 
  boolean txtFound = driver.getPageSource().contains(value);
  try{
   if(txtFound = true)
   log.log(value + " : text Found, .......continue");
   return txtFound;  
  }catch(Exception e)
  {
   log.log(value + " :NOT Found, check element again or Contact developer.");
   return false;
  } 
 }`

Comment: @Joe you should learn to use a debugger, that would allow you to waste way less time on mistakes like this one

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't it be the other way around?

```
Assert.assertTrue("Message if it is false", callMethod.verifyTextPresent("SIGN IN"));
```

Comment: If it is `org.junit.Assert`, you're definitely right. But then, how could the code compile?

Comment: I used ....... import static org.junit.Assert.*; verifyTextPresent() is in my method class while verifySignOutBtn()  is in my main. hope that answers your question.